# Will side-effects be executed in this if clause

Tags: php, if-statement

**Does the function `add_new_user` run the SQL INSERT query if it is inside the if clause?**

I have the functions

```
function add_new_user ( $username, $email, $passhash_md5 )
{
    -- cut: database INSERT queries
    return 1;                                                                                                
}
```

I use the code above as

```
if ( validate( $username, $password, $email ) == 1 ) {
    if ( add_new_user ( $username, $email, $passhash_md5 )  == 1 ) {   
                // problem here
              -- cut
    }                                                                                                        
}
```

I asked this question because I am not sure why [this handler](http://dpaste.com/84364/) always gives unsuccessful registraton notice. The two codes belong to the handler. The bug seems to be in the syntax of my code and perhaps in the use of if/else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the function add_new_user run the
>   SQL INSERT query if it is inside the
>   if -clause?

Yes

```
function foo() {
  echo 'A';
  return true;
}

function bar() {
  echo 'B';
  return false;
}

if ( foo() ) {
  if ( bar() ) {
    echo 'C';
  }
}
// Output: AB
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

The function first get's evaluated for it's return value.

After the return value is known, the return value is compared to the integer value 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Anything between the `if (` and the `) {` is run to see if it is true. You can do anything in here really.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has to evaluate the boolean expression in order to know if it will execute the block or not. So, to evaluate the "==" operator, it needs to evaluate both sides, including the function "add_new_user".

So, the answer is: **yes**, it will evaluate the function add_new_user AND **it will execute the insert operation** (unless you have some code inside add_new_user that will block this).

However, you are doing something that should be avoided when possible: you are using a condition with side-effects! This will give you headaches (for example, right now!).

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by side-effects. Your answer however suggests me that it is not needed to check if the function has been accessed. **I would still like to see if the query was successuful somehow.**

Comment: Side-effects are things like: writing to disk/streams/database, opening connections, etc. You should know which function have side-effects (add_new_user has one, for instance). Then, you must know that when you call these functions, the side-effect will occur. Your original question could be rephrased as: "will the side-effect get executed with this 'if' statement?". Sure, you HAVE to check if it was succesful, and your way of doing it is not bad. Just keep in mind what I said about side-effects. Google for "pure function" or "side-effect free function" for more info!